# Can I get this question question reopened?

Tags: discussion

This question [Is there any way to check for badblocks that address the two issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/1606689/is-there-any-way-to-check-for-badblocks-that-address-the-two-issues) get flagged as opinion based. But it's not. Some guy posted an totally untrue opinion based answer, but I really want my questions to be solved. I really want someone to come up with good ways to test for badblocks.

I have asked here [What to do when someone with more reputation trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357393/what-to-do-when-someone-with-more-reputation-trying-to-mislead-my-question-into) then @Rob lead me to ask here on meta.superuser.com

Comment: As one of the close voters I have indicated twice, that the question still needs improvements before I can justify one of my very valuable daily reopen votes.  Your focused on the fact it was closed as an opinion when in reality it was closed for multiple reasons and that simply was the reason that got the most votes.   **Additionally, you have made it impossible to reopen, once you deleted it**

Answer (score 4):

### Why do you think someone with more reputation than you abused their reputation to post an answer you disagree with?

#### Stop taking opinions you don’t agree with as political acts designed to sabotage you.

I think the main reason it was closed was *your* desire to blame others for providing you with a real answer. And the answer is what it is: Don’t worry about it.

But as far as your attitude goes — which can be a reason for closure — can be seen as follows in [this rant in your closed question](https://superuser.com/questions/1606689/is-there-any-way-to-check-for-badblocks-that-address-the-two-issues):

> Also my question get an opinion-based answer by @dirkt but it't not opinion based. Of course @dirkt claimed that *all modern* drives don't need to check for badblocks it totally not true, I'm sure drives produced **this year** have bad blocks! I have some USB drive tested a few months ago and they did have bad blocks (this is real)!! I really want to ask for a good way to check for badblocks that address the above two issues!

You don’t get an answer you like, ignore it. Don’t blame someone for posting an answer. But then you go to [Meta Stack Exchange and state this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357393/what-to-do-when-someone-with-more-reputation-trying-to-mislead-my-question-into):

> “What to do when someone with more reputation trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question?”

Then you say:

> “So what to do with someone with more reputation trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question? It appears he abused his reputation to express his opinions not really want to provide methods to solve questions.”

Where are you getting the idea that someone with more reputation is “trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question?” You got an answer you don’t like. Without that answer the question has an opinion-based aspect to it. How did the user in question “abused his reputation?” Someone who is new and has no reputation could have posted an answer. Why do you think their reputation has anything to do with the content of their post?

They simply posted a “Don’t worry about it…” answer which you might disagree with. And you can choose to comment as such or even downvote it. But I am pretty sure the four community members who chose to close your question weren’t motivated by an answer posters reputation.

Reading your question, you provide decent details but I honestly see the opinion-based aspect to this as well as a noble level of “too broad”-ness to the question as well. Your question leans more on a philosophical solution to an issue that is honestly not a true problem most would be concerned with.

Comment: I honestly face **true** problems with real drives with badblocks. If anyone did not face badblocks drive problems, just ignore my question. But anyway badblocks are there. Why posting opinions trying to persuade me ignore true problems?

Comment: BTW, people write badblock checking softwares and there are many. All these people are facing not true problems?

Comment: I want good methods to detect them that's it.

Comment: @Nublia - That is exactly the reason I voted to close your question as “too broad”.  You really need to narrow the focus of your question.  For instance what is wrong with the manufactures SMART utilities or something like TestDisk?

Comment: @Ramhound manufactures' SMART are not opensource, there are cases that SMART can't detect badblocks (https://superuser.com/questions/462233/bad-blocks-detected-by-fsck-smart-says-disk-is-good). TestDisk is for data recovery not for detecting badblocks.

Comment: You made no mention you wanted open source solutions, of course it would not really matter, the correct tool is the correct tool in a case like this.  There really are not a lot of tools that can do want you want

Comment: Hard drives are closed source. The block level of the hard drives is viewable directly only by the drive controller. Open source tools are VERY unlikely to be able to reverse engineer a drives' internal code and structures to be able to converse or read the hardware layer. .Dirkt is right and your opinions otherwise are incorrect, no matter how much you want them not to be.